# Nuget package for image rotating feature

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I tried searching but I did not get.I came across [ImageResizer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx) but I am not sure about how to use it. Is there any other nuget package that provides the image rotation feature?

Comment: Possibly want to edit your question as it is quite confusing

Answer (score 3):

In imageresizer

The command is listed on

http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference

srotate=0|90|180|270 Rotates the source image prior to processing (only 90 degree intervals) (new in V3.1).

Comment: ok got it.But I have to hard code srotate=90 everytime, is there some way where I can use this dynamically?

Comment: What I want to do is rotate the image automatically to the correct orientation irrespective of the orientation in which it was upload. I was going through the image resizing docs, will `autorotate=true` help me achieve this? Its a live app, so if I want to test it I will have to host the project

Comment: Hi @sumedha i would really need to see where you are putting this specifically in your code

Comment: Hi @P6345uk this is the code `<img src="~/Content/img/mbcarpentry.jpg?autorotate=true&height=200" />`

Comment: auto rotate will rotate to the angle that the picture was taken. 
Is this what you want (if this data is available)? I had understood from your previous comment you wanted to rotate 90 degrees?